# My speaker connected to my TV is making weird noises only when playing videos

Tags: audio, adc, tv, digital-audio, optical

Apologies if this is the incorrect forum, if anyone knows of a better forum to ask on I would appreciate the redirection.

I have a very specific issue regarding audio playback from my TV. I have a Samsung smart TV that only has an optical audio out port. I purchased an ADC converter that converts from optical to audio left and right. I then have an audio left and right to single aux 3.5mm cable which I connect directly to the speaker. The setup works in general, native TV sound has no issues, as well as a Nintendo Switch connected via HDMI, or audio played from a USB drive.

The issue occurs only when trying to play video files from a USB drive. Regardless of video file format, the audio glitches out creating a hiccupy static effect. This sound continues even when the video is stopped, the TV is switched off, or the TV audio settings are switched back to the built-in speakers. Switching the TV back on, playing an audio file or starting up the Switch is successful in resetting the sound. If the speaker is switched off and on again, the weird sound resumes.

The issue is neither with the drive, nor the speakers, I have tested with multiple. This leads me to suspect the issue must lie with the converter, but I am not sure and have no idea how to troubleshoot. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be the TV alone or the DAC alone or then it is a combination of both together, and troubleshooting requires analyzing the audio data stream and how the DAC reacts to it, with tools like oscilloscope and logic analyzer, most likely reverse-engineering the DAC as well to know what to measure and how.

Comment: An audio recording of the defective sound would be interesting, is that possible?

Comment: @Justme unfortunately I do not have that equipment at home to be able to do that.

Comment: @TypeIA I should be able to in a few hours.

Comment: @TypeIA Recording the optical output will tell very little. Recorders may anyway resample the incoming data to local audio clocks. And even if it did not resample, the problem may not be visible in the recording. If the TV slides the sampling rate slowly into place when changing between audio streams, it won't show up in the recording, but the DAC may also want to resample to local clocks but does not assume clock sliding and will keep itself resynced after input clocks have changed. Been there.

Comment: @Justme I meant any audible recording of the glitchy sound... not a digital capture of the SPDIF. It may offer clues beyond the written description as the nature of the "glitch" isn't totally clear. Or it may not, as you say. (Also been there, I'm heavily involved in audio and DAQ.)

Comment: Is it 50/60 Hz humming or more "clicks"? My cheap digital coax -> RCA does click from time to time.

Comment: Hmm, is the TV audio settings set to output Stereo Linear PCM only, no bitstream/compressed/Dolby/DTS allowed?

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect a bug in the TV, making it send wrong data on the optical output. However, if it plays videos from USB drive with normal sound on its internal speakers, then this should not be the case.

Another possibility is the TV outputting a compressed format on the optical output, like some Dolby formats, if the movie was encoded with such a format. This is supposed to be received by an AV receiver, which decompresses it and decodes it to multichannel audio. If you have a stereo DAC which does not have the software and chips to decode this, but is not smart enough to know it should mute it, then it will sound like white noise.

Another issue would be sample rate: specifically if the TV outputs normal audio, but at a sample rate that is not supported by the DAC. This can occur if the movie is encoded with such a sample rate, or if the player resamples the audio to a sample rate that is unsupported by the DAC.

Most optical receivers only work reliably up to 96k. Some do 192k perfectly, some not at all, and some receive 192k with enough errors to make it unusable but not enough errors to make it not work at all. So, the RX chip can get enough data without errors to decide it's gonna work, so it starts playing, and you get some garbled audio until it decides there are too many errors, mutes, and does it all over again.

The fact your DAC continues to misbehave after the TV is turned off does make me think about a sample rate issue, because it's pretty much the only state variable a stereo DAC would preserve when the source shuts down. I talked about sample rate being too high earlier, but maybe it's too low, or your DAC just doesn't support it. I would suggest using a PC with an optical output, and sending audio with various sample rates to the DAC to see what happens.